# String cannot be converted to int error when trying to return

Tags: java, string, int, return

So im trying to write a java program for school. It has to convert US time, for example 3PM into european time, 15 in this case. So this is the part where i tranform 24 into 12AM and return it to previous method for printing

```
if (timeDigit == 0 ){
        timeDigit = 12;
        String suffix = "AM";
        return timeDigit; 
        return suffix;
```

But when i try to compile then i get error: String cannot be converted to int

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you have two `return` statements which doesn't make sense... also, your method probably is declared to return a `String` and in your first `return` you are trying to return `timeDigit` which is an `int`...

Comment: You should post the entire code of the method. What you posted so far doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Probably your method in which this code written, returns `String`. Since the first `return` statement is of type `int`, you're getting this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one you can't return twice in the same method.  When the first return is called the 2nd one will never be executed.  The problem is your method is returning type int and you are trying to return a String.

```
public int converTime() // if you notice it has int in the method that means it is expecting an int not a string
     return int;
```

The compiler sees that you are trying to return a string (after you return the int) and says "hey you can't return a string here i am expecting an int".

Maybe you should change your method to return string and return both in one statement like:

```
public String convertTime()
{
    String timeDigit = "12";
    String suffix = "AM";
    String output = null;
    output = timeDigit + suffix;
    return output;
}

public void main(String args[])
{
   String output = convertTime();
   System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: I haven't found a way to send you a message so i will just ask it here. I fixed the previous problem but now when i try to print a string i get error that the variable im trying to print has not been yet initialised.
But i have made a new string using #String output = new String (timeDigit + suffix);#

Comment: If you declare String output in your method you can only access it from within the method.  That is why you would return output and access it from the returned String.  Or you could create a global variable and use that but that would not be as clean.  In your main method where you call it try something like above i posted more code.

Answer (score 0):

... You know both those returns won't fire right? I'm willing to bet that your return type (the thing right before your function name) is an int, and your second return (the one that will never get called) is trying to return a string. string and int aren't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly do you want, but this code returns "12AM".

`public String returnTime(int timeDigit) {
    String suffix = "AM";
    if (timeDigit == 0 ){
        timeDigit = 12;
    }
        return String.valueOf(timeDigit)+suffix;
    }`